# What is .I extension used for?

Tags: c++, file-format

I was following [this](http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/3/) tutorial for learning how to create a Compiler in c++. But in the tutorial the author created `tokens.I` file for lexical analysis.

Can anyone please tell me what is `.I` extension used for ??

Thank You

Comment: Are you sure it was `.I` and not `.l` (which look remarkably similar in many sans serif fonts, but the first is a capital i and the second a lower-case L).  A `.l` file is use by Lex or Flex — it contains the source code for a lexical analyzer.

Comment: From the referenced URL: **Listing of tokens.l:**. Yes, it is lowercase **L**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extension is actually `.l` (lowercase L), which is used for a "lex" file.

Answer (score 1):

Intermediate files between the C preprocessor and the C compiler. All macros are expanded here.

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

http://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/I-Intermediate-file-Borland-C

To quote:

> I is an intermediate preprocessor output file format used by Borland C++. I files are used to compile and communicate a stream of binary tokens between the compiler’s parsers. I files can also be used to compose textual outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some basic knowledge of compiler, quoted from http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/:

> A compiler or interptreter for a programminning language is often decomposed into two parts:
>
> ```
> 1. Read the source program and discover its structure.
> 2. Process this structure, e.g. to generate the target program.
> ```
>
> The task of discovering the source structure again is decomposed into subtasks:
>
> ```
>  a. Split the source file into tokens
>  b. Find the hierarchical structure of the program
> ```

And there are lots of tools to do task a for you, like `Lex`, `Flex` or `Re2c`. So basically you can define some token parsing rules (using regular expression) in a `.l` file according to tool's grammer, then pass it to those tool and let them do token parsing for you.